# What is the difference between Forward slash and Backslash in Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a import some csv file in Pandas with using of Forward slash and Backslash. How Can I know which file will be use with forward and Backslash?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9sr1.png)

Please tell me answer as soon as possible.